# Change on hold message to include reopen vote instructions

Tags: feature-request, on-hold

One of my questions was recently put on hold. This was the first time it ever happened, so I didnt really know what to do. I improved the question to quality standards, but it wasnt put off hold, and I didnt know how to get it off. So I decided to make a new question which was a repeat. Sufficed to say, the same people who put me on hold last time came again and started yelling at me, flaming ensued, etc.

I did not find out until after that there was a (very hard to see) reopen button. The on hold message already instructs you to improve the quality of your post, so it would be simple to just tack on "and then press reopen to start a vote" at the end of it. It would have saved me some hassle and a flame war :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes

Comment: @Doorknob I dont think a simple check for rep level would be too hard either.

Comment: Perhaps it could give these instructions to a user in a confirmation popup of some sort *after* the user has edited. Putting them in the normal instructions would just encourage users to skip to reopening without improvement.

Comment: It's also worth noting that *the very act of submitting an edit* sticks it in the reopen review queue.

Comment: @Charles I did not know this. That should definitely be posted clearly somewhere.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Do you mean the on hold text? You can just find any old on hold question

Comment: @PatrickHofman No, I get the same on hold message as everyone, Im just saying the message can be improved.